# Difference between using 2 and 3 polarizer

Tags: optics, quantum-optics

Is there a difference in using 2, 3 or more polarizer? Is there anything that 3 polarizer can do but not 2 polarizer cannot?

Comment: What do you mean by "do"? Is it in terms of the states of light (and/or transformations on light) that can be effected? Or in terms of the experiments that can be performed? (Hint: the answer changes depending on which of those you choose.)

Comment: The effect of using 2 and 3 polarizer on an object shows different effect. So, why does it happen?

Comment: That's an entirely different question; if that's what you're really asking, then you should **edit** your post so that it reflects a clear question instead of adding it in the comments. (Though that said, if that is your question, you should do a thorough search of the existing corpus, starting with [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61918) and the ones on its Linked sidebar to the right, to make sure that what you're asking hasn't been posted before, so that your question doesn't get immediately re-closed as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a famous undergraduate experiment that involves 2 and 3 polarizers and yields different results based on this. It consists of a light source, 2 polarizers at specific angles and a detector.

If both polarizers are parallel, light passes through and can be detected. If they are perpendicular to each other, all of the light is blocked and nothing is detected.

Finally, if a third polarizing filter is included between the perpendicular filters and placed at a 45° angle, some light can again pass through.

[image]